# numpy vstack vs concatenate

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Currently I am playing around with numpy and I noticed the following similarity between concatenate and vstack for a singular 3d numpy array:

```
np.vstack(mat.T) == np.concatenate(mat.T, axis=0)
```

I'm a little bit behind with my linear algebra skills so I was just wondering if this would always hold true for all 3d arrays.

Comment: This isn't linear algebra.  `vstack` is just `concatenate` on axis 0, with the added step of making sure the inputs are at least 2d.  What's your `mat`?  Usually these functions are used to join a list of arrays into one.  `vstack` is written in python so you can see exactly what it's doing.

Comment: I suspect that you could do the same transformation with a combination of `transpose` and `reshape`.  Like `mat.T.reshape(-1,mat.shape[0])`